# Can't find template StringTemplate

Tags: antlr, antlr3, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I am trying to create a wiki app in google app engine. I am using String Template. But I don't understand template file hierarchy.

Here is the code.

- necessary imports done.

  ```
  public class Add extends HttpServlet{

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //super.doPost(req, resp);
  DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

  String title = req.getParameter("title");
  Entity articleEntity = new Entity("Article", normalize(title));
  articleEntity.setProperty("title", title);

  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
  if(user != null){
      String author = user.getNickname();
      articleEntity.setProperty("author", author);
  }else{
      String author = "Anonymous";
      articleEntity.setProperty("author", author);
  }

  String content = req.getParameter("content");
  Text myContent = new Text(content);
  articleEntity.setProperty("content", myContent);

  datastoreService.put(articleEntity);

  resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
   }

    private String normalize(String str){
  String trimmedLower = str.toLowerCase().trim();
  String urlReady = trimmedLower.replace(" ", "-");
  return urlReady;
  }

  }
  ```

And here is the directory structure.
[image: directroy]

I am getting this error

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /page. Reason:

Can't find template retrieve-article.st; group hierarchy is [xhtml]
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find template retrieve-article.st; group hierarchy is [xhtml]
at       org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.lookupTemplate(StringTemplateGroup.java:507)
at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.getInstanceOf(StringTemplateGroup.java:392)
at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.getInstanceOf(StringTemplateGroup.java:404)
at in.isuru.wiki.Page.doGet(Page.java:42)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Powered by Jetty://

Answer (score 3):

Try avoiding '-' in template names.
Ter

Comment: I also found that having "." in my path caused it to not find the file as well.